# Table Valued Function in Entity Framework 5 VS 2012 not mapping

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, user-defined-functions, asp.net-4.5

Just installed Visual Studio Web Express 2012 just so that I could map TVFs. But I find that, while the functions import to the model as the expected complex types, they do not show up in the model diagram.

The model is database first, which is supposed to support mapping TVFs. And the TVFs work perfectly.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? I'm wondering if VS 2012 express has limited features. I've also noticed that it does not persist a database connection from one session to another.

Answer (score 0):

Complex types are never shown in the diagram. You can see them only in model browser and as a type for complex properties defined in your entities. That is not related to TVF mapping. TVF should be available as method on generated context class - VS2012 Express should have no limitation in this.

Comment: Thanks very much. I guess I was assuming that they would diagram as complex types.